# Does the game's sexual content affect gameplay?

Tags: the-witcher

I'm new to the Witcher franchise of games. In a recent discussion about the sexual content by the gaming community, there was mention of the sexual content in The Witcher 3. I'm now playing The Witcher (first game) Enhanced Edition and noticed that the sexual content is definitely a piece of the game. However, what is the relevance of the sexual content in The Witcher Enhanced Edition with regards to gameplay? Does it give special abilities, items, money or change the story of the game in some way?

Comment: No........................................

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting it, the question seems valid. They want to know if they will be missing out on anything important by skipping the sexually related content. It's a fair question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be missing anything from the game's story no. The first game's whole sexual themes are the girls you find on the street and interact with them... Mostly it's just a side objective / collecting type of thing. However I can assure you 95% of the game's content is sexual content free. And it does not affect your inventory (unless there's a side quest with one of those girls on the streets which are not that common afaik) but nothing related to the main story. So basically, doesn't influence your game in any major way whatsoever.

The Witcher 2 on the other hand has some sexual content right off the bat that DOES affect the story if you don't watch it. But since I never really played the Witcher 2 that much, I can't tell you much about it but expect a lot more sexual content as you go from Witcher 1 to Witcher 2 (keep in mind the controls and gameplay change from the first game to the second drastically)